# Dynamic Linq query on relationship with foreign key of type Guid

Tags: c#, sql, expression-trees, dynamic-linq

I'm using [System.Linq.Dynamic](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/) to query an IQueryable datasource dynamically using a where-clause in a string format, like this:

```
var result = source.Entities.Where("City = @0", new object[] { "London" });
```

The example above works fine. But now I want to query on a foreign key-property of type Guid like this:

```
var result = source.Entities.Where("CompanyId = @0", new object[] { "838AD581-CEAB-4B44-850F-D05AB3D791AB" });
```

This won't work because a Guid can't be compared to a string by default. And I have to provide the guid as a string because it's originally coming from a json-request and json does not support guid's.

Firstly, is this even a correct way of querying over a relationship or is there an other syntax for doing this?

Secondly, how do I modify Dynamic.cs from the Dynamic Linq-project to automatically convert a string to guid if the entity-property being compared with is of type guid?

Comment: why you pass string as parameter instead of Guid? try use `Guid.Parse` and pass guid

Comment: As I wrote, the query is coming from a json-request and I can't go through a convert possible guid-strings to guids. It would be best if the Dynamic.cs could be modified to detect when I try to compare a Guid with a string and do the conversion then instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many ways for solving. Simplest, as i think, will be change your query like this

```
var result = source.Entities.Where("CompanyId.Equals(@0)", new object[] { Guid.Parse("838AD581-CEAB-4B44-850F-D05AB3D791AB") });
```

If you want use operators `=` and `==` then in `Dynamic.cs` you need change `interface IEqualitySignatures : IRelationalSignatures` like this

```
interface IEqualitySignatures : IRelationalSignatures
{
    ....
    F(Guid x, Guid y);
    ....
}
```

after that you can use next query

```
var result = source.Entities.Where("CompanyId=@0", new object[] { Guid.Parse("838AD581-CEAB-4B44-850F-D05AB3D791AB") });
```

OR

```
var result = source.Entities.Where("CompanyId==@0", new object[] { Guid.Parse("838AD581-CEAB-4B44-850F-D05AB3D791AB") });
```

But if you want use `string` parameter you need change `ParseComparison` method in `ExpressionParser` class. You need add yet another checking for operand types like this

```
....
//you need add this condition
else if(left.Type==typeof(Guid) && right.Type==typeof(string)){
    right = Expression.Call(typeof(Guid).GetMethod("Parse"), right);
}
//end condition
else {
    CheckAndPromoteOperands(isEquality ? typeof(IEqualitySignatures) : typeof(IRelationalSignatures), op.text, ref left, ref right, op.pos);
}
....
```

and then you query will be work

```
var result = source.Entities.Where("CompanyId = @0", new object[] { "838AD581-CEAB-4B44-850F-D05AB3D791AB" });
```